# Paste\Return into Cell A1 of open Excel sheet

Tags: excel, powershell

I wish to take a string generated in PowerShell and paste\return that string into Cell A:1 of an OPEN spreadsheet. I have researched this but I dont understand the excel specific syntax.
 Do I need to identify and declare the PID for the specific Excel workbook thats running and if so how?

I know how to create a new workbook and add the text to cell A:1 but not one which is already open. It must also "press return" to execute the spreadsheet functions once pasted.

I dont know where to start other than: ((new-object -com "excel.application").Workbooks.Add()).application.Visible=$True

I have scoured the web but have not found any examples that make sense. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using the below script

```
#Specify the path of the excel file
$FilePath = "path\test.xlsx"

#Specify the Sheet name
$SheetName = "Sheet1"

# Create an Object Excel.Application using Com interface
$objExcel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')

# Disable the 'visible' property so the document won't open in excel
$objExcel.Visible = $false

# Open the Excel file and save it in $WorkBook
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

# Load the WorkSheet 'BuildSpecs'
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName)
$WorkSheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = "Link" #Updates the first cell (A1)
$WorkBook.Save()
$WorkBook.Close()
```

Make sure the file has write permissions from PowerShell scripts.

If you want to edit the sheet which is already open, change the path of the file and mention the sheet name properly and it would work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Ng-Suhas, will test this asap

Comment: @IanB Test this script and if you find any issues, feel free to ping me back. If it works, please accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: Will it work if the Excel Sheet is already open? I also assume “link” on third last line is just the text I want to paste into cell A:1 ?

Comment: Yes, it should work even if the excel file is open! And yes the link on the third last line is the text that you want to replace into the cell A:1.

Comment: And will it invoke a return (press enter) once the cell A:1 has the texted pasted?

Comment: Yes, you should acknowledge the dialog box because you have already a write lock on that respective file.